# Camel Custom Component

Tags: components, apache-camel

Is this possible?

```
  <bean id="camelCustomComponent" class="x.y.z.CustomComponent" />
```

Below is the camel route

```
  <to uri="camelCustomComponent:someThing?SomeParams=someValues" />
```

This is to leverage the camel component user/developer to use their name whatever they want.

I understand their should be a file with name camelCustomComponent which will have the Custom Component's class name.
Can we make dynamic.
Is it possible to initialise the component dynamically?

Thanks.

Regards
Senthil Kumar Sekar

Answer (score 2):

I see two options.

1. Create a full component as per the [Writing Components](http://camel.apache.org/writing-components.html) guide, the important point being that you will need to create a file under **META-INF/services** for your **camelCustomComponent:** URI to be detect by Camel.
2. Use the [Bean Component](http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html) which has some support for setting method parameter values. See the section titled **Parameter binding using method option**

Answer (score 1):

Yes as bgossit posted, see the documentation about writing a component

- http://camel.apache.org/writing-components.html

And the options in the uris, are just getter/setter in the endpoint class. That is all you need to do.

You can for example copy an existing component and use that for creating your own, for example if the component is similar to yours.

But better yet, maybe use the maven archetype to create a new component as documented here

- http://camel.apache.org/camel-maven-archetypes.html

Comment: I totally understand that to create a Custom component,we need to
(i) Component, Endpoint, Producer and Consumers Classes + file under META-INF which will have the Component Class name.

My question here is that I will create a bean which will do some task
<bean id="myCamelCustomComponent" class="x.y.z.CamelCustomComponent" 
/>

Comment: Yes you can define a < bean > for your component and the id is the component name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am not able to find any documentation.It would be of great help if you can point me through one.